# Moving Map Under the Marker in Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am new in MapBox iOS SDK  and I need to add a marker in the center of MGLMapView so that user would be able to move map view under the marker and the marker would be fix on the screen. I also need to get the coordinate of the point in the map that is under the marker. I could not find any method in Mapbox SDK and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is quite easy. Add an image of a marker on top of the map to give the visual effect so the user can still scroll around without moving the marker. Then you can get the center coordinates usually quite easily using `mapView.centerCoordinate` when the user stops scrolling.

Here is the [API documentation link](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(py)centerCoordinate) for reference

Comment: but when I add a marker by addAnnotation on the mapView and then scroll the map, the marker moves with map.

Comment: Add the marker as a separate view above the MGLMapView, not as an annotation of the MGLMapView.  Then just add constraints to keep the top view centered over the MGLMapView underneath it.

Comment: @MarkThormann thanks for the help clarifying. Yeah the easy way is to not actually add a marker, add a image of a marker on top of the view, then it wouldn't scroll. otherwise you'd need to listen for any pan movement, or try and observe the center value and update the position of an actual marker, but it rarely stays perfectly in position doing it that way, it lags behind and 'wobbles' around the center

Comment: How would we know that our map stopped moving? And get the center Coordinates? @HastiRanjkesh

Comment: @HashirSaeed I believe there are delegate methods to show when the map has been scrolled/panned. I haven't used this SDK in a while so I'm not sure of the exact ones but they

Comment: Okay!. Thank you. I will search for it!.

Comment: How would you do to have the floating marker a little higher than the center of the map on the Y axis? and also get the coordinates of that marker @Scriptable

Comment: I think that there is a method to select a point on the map, usually used for manually handling taps. you could pass the position of the marker in maybe. I haven't used it in a while so this is just a guess. but should give you some ideas

Answer (score 1):

I had done something like this in one of my apps

1) Add map to UIViewController

2) Add a Transparent view on top of the map in UIViewController. (May need to set userInteractionEnabled to false. Not sure though!)

3) Add marker image to the Transparent view so that its bottom tip is at the center of the view it is added to.

4) Get center coordinates by using `mapView.centerCoordinate`

Comment: You can add the marker image directly on top of the map, or add it as a subview. you dont need a transparent view I dont think

Comment: If so even better. :)

Comment: @Scriptable Ok, Thank you.

Comment: How would you do to have the floating marker a little higher than the center of the map on the Y axis? and also get the coordinates of that marker.

Comment: @GaboRuiz I would suggest you to use annotations on the map view. That would allow you to move the marker around and get the coordinates automatically

Comment: Im doing that. the floating marker its just for positioning the annotation. I need to put that annotation just a little bit up in the y axis, because it pins in the center of the map. @iOSer

Comment: So umm, If i get it right? Its just a place holder to let your user know where to position the annotation? If coordinates don't matter then whatever the longitude of the center negate a value (5 or 10 or 20). Hit and try, sort of thing, until you settle on the one you think is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For other people who have this issue too:

```
let markerImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Orange"))
markerImageView.center = mapView.center
mapView.addSubview(markerImageView)
```