# Grab coordinates of the centre of the map with Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Is it possible to have a Marker stays in the middle of the map and grab the coordinates, while the user moves around the map? Like the map in Uber and Deliveroo.

I saw this for mapbox-ios-sdk [Moving Map Under the Marker in Mapbox iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498237/moving-map-under-the-marker-in-mapbox-ios-sdk), but I can't find anything on mapbox-gl-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates with `map.getCenter().toArray()`;

To have a static marker in the middle, the easiest way is to simply overlay a separate DOM element (like an `img` or `div`) that is not part of the map. Just position it so that it's exactly centered.